# output GPS data onto ROS topics

Tags: gps, ros

Is there anybody has ever used Trimble GPS (global positioning system) receiver, and wrote any GPS driver to output GPS data onto ROS (robot operating system) topics?

Comment: Did you try [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=ROS+GPS) for this?

Answer (score 0):

If your Trimble outputs NMEA sentences, you should be able to use the [nmea_navsat_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_navsat_driver) to read them. If you can read them via serial port, you can try the nmea_serial_driver to publish directly from the port. If it outputs via some other protocol (e.g. TCP or UDP), you'll need to write your own driver to get the NMEA sentences onto ROS topics - at that point you can use the nmea_topic_driver to process the raw sentences.